# Clarification needed about a SSL client using Boost asio

Tags: c++, ssl, https

I have a C++ application that uses Boost_asio to do TCP/IP connection who read a .php document in a Web server that in turn uses the php script to update certain statistics.

The whole thing work as planned, but recently the server changed to use SSL (Google mandatory) and naturally, the previous connection stopped to work.

After a lot of theoretical reading about SSL, I'm still in the dark about certain practical details.

Using the example in the [Boost asio documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/client.cpp) and a file “cacert.pem”, downloaded form somewhere following indications in **this** site, I'm able to run correctly the example using:

```
<host> = “www.google.com” and <port> = “https”.
```

Using the example “as is”, the Google server response is:

> Verifying /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
>   Verifying /C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
>   Verifying /C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=www.google.com
>   Enter message: Reply:

But when using

```
<host> =  “www.zator.com” and <port> =  “https”
```

my domain, hosted in 1&1 IONOS, the reply is:

> Handshake failed: tlsv1 alert internal error

At this point I have **several questions**:

What in the hell mean the sentence:  `ctx.load_verify_file("cacert.pem");` ?

The content of that file, can be the culprit of the fail when connecting with my domain?

Is that sentence essential to complete the connection?

In the case of google server (absence of error), is it supposed that after the sentence `io_context.run();` the connection has been correctly established?

Assuming I make public the client's member `socket_` (private in the example), can I continue with some as (I can't test that in google :-)

```
std::string request("GET /mystatistics.php HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
boost::asio::write(c.socket_, boost::asio::buffer(request));
boost::system::error_code ec;
std::string response;
do {        // read response
    char buf[1024];
    size_t bytes_transferred = c.socket_.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), ec);
    if (!ec) response.append(buf, buf + bytes_transferred);
} while (!ec);
std::cout << "Response received: '" << response << "'\n";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found some useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324425/what-is-boostasiosslcontextload-verify-file-and-how-to-work-with-it). A good, albeit partial info, and a good start point to further search