# OpenSSL encrypted streams

Tags: c++, openssl, iostream

Does anyone know a good implementation for encrypted **C++** streams using **OpenSSL** ?
Something that extends or wraps **std::istream** and **std::ostream** ?

I know this could be done with boost (filtering stream) but I don't want to include boost just for that. Any non boost suggestions ?

Comment: If you're adding a dependency anyway, what's wrong with boost?

Comment: Yeah, this seems odd. You want to add OpenSSL as a dependency, *as well as* some other unspecified dependency which wraps the former in a C++ stream. So... why can't this unspecified dependency be a Boost library?

Comment: @jalf: OpenSSL is already added as a dependency. I want to avoid using boost because of the already huge compiling time. Should I choose to use boost I will still have to wrap it and implement the actual filters. This can be done, but I would like something better.

Comment: Boost is rather modular package, so adding it as dependency shouldn't increase compile times much - you don't need to compile entire boost, but just the part you need - usually just a few header files.

Answer (score 3):

Boost library provides ssl stream:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/asio/ssl/stream.hpp

SO ref : [HTTPS request with Boost.Asio and OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046370/https-request-with-boost-asio-and-openssl)

Answer (score 1):

I came across following implementations using std::istream and std::ostream.

1. AES CTR-mode encryption/decryption

http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/EVP-Decrypt-Final-ex-fails-on-larger-files-td2434.html

1. Blowfish

http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/EVP-Decrypt-Final-ex-fails-on-larger-files-td2434.html

Additionally, you can also look here:

http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Crypto.RSAKeyImpl.html

and here:

https://dev.marc.waeckerlin.org/projects/libpcscxx/browser/trunk/src/openssl.hxx?rev=60

Comment: unfortunately your links don't show how to wrap std::istream and std::ostream, they only show how to use them as input and output for the encrypt-decrypt method.

Comment: I want to wrap the streams so that decryption/encryption can be done transparently by my application without having to use a temporary file or a temporary memory chunk.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it yourself:

Subclass std::streambuf for use with TCP or SSL (they basically work the same once the socket is open.  Then you can make std::istream and std::ostream using that streambuf.  If you don't want std::iostream, you could make two streambufs, one for input and one for output.

std::streambuf docs (mostly just focus on overflow and underflow): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/

And a small tutorial on how to use libssl directly.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl/index.html

Comment: +1 Because this is close to what I want to achieve. This seems to dangerous to me, I haven't implemented something like this before, and many of the virtual methods that I would have to implement, not just overflow and underflow, are a bit cryptic to me.

Comment: It's worth doing at least once.  Mainly so you can learn how stdlib's stream functions work.  The documentation is relatively straight forward.