# Boost Asio HTTPS request giving 'certificate verify failed' error

Tags: c++, boost, https, boost-asio

I'm trying to read data over an HTTPS connection using Boost.Asio from a C++ application. I'm working off a similiar SO question ([HTTPS request with Boost.Asio and OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046370/https-request-with-boost-asio-and-openssl)), but am still getting a 'certificate verify failled' error.

I've updated the code slightly - using Google instead since the www.mtgox.com site has changed and is giving me browser warnings about self-signed certificates. Google's certificate chain I imagine would be free of these problems.

I've downloaded the issuer certificate and confirm that it works ok from the command line:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts  -CApath ./certs -connect google.com:443
```

gives me:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Equifax, OU = Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Inc, CN = Google Internet Authority
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc, CN = *.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2744 bytes and written 348 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
    Session-ID: A69DDC4E1D33F3D03603AED0CC9F101CC1A49BEE76D61AC0508A780D9E2AF06A
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 8B08C4A8FB1332EE278F037B115EB4E3E6EF51BCE464B05F8B0652A2773FD34FC2F769B2AB51DCC57CF9844A8B747F97
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 1f 6b 71 a9 3c 1f 83 b0-ad 45 ee 74 5f bb d6 3f   .kq.<....E.t_..?
    0010 - 06 a3 01 3a a6 00 53 da-b2 72 9b 16 d5 5f 54 75   ...:..S..r..._Tu
    0020 - 7e 35 10 1d c8 7e 6e 9e-29 dc f1 67 97 aa 94 77   ~5...~n.)..g...w
    0030 - 81 f5 a4 6c 25 29 61 13-12 6b d3 13 86 40 95 ae   ...l%)a..k...@..
    0040 - d0 6b d9 1f 9e 62 a4 09-68 8a fb 7b 6a b0 34 74   .k...b..h..{j.4t
    0050 - 57 0e 2f 45 d8 e9 9c 10-af 43 dc 83 b7 bd 8f 63   W./E.....C.....c
    0060 - 5e 84 d4 e1 bd 8a 18 55-de 4b a7 58 1e 9d b1 bf   ^......U.K.X....
    0070 - 84 de bb 0b 4a 9b 46 7f-cf 94 8b e3 48 53 54 49   ....J.F.....HSTI
    0080 - 1a 3b f9 41 4b 08 fc ac-b6 09 f0 5b 65 bf e3 cd   .;.AK......[e...
    0090 - 62 7b ad e4                                       b{..

    Start Time: 1363898770
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

If i then type in

```
GET
```

I get the html/javascript code for the Google home page, which is what I'd expect.

However, my code still fails. (I've tried to make it as short as possible):

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>


class client
{
public:
  client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context& context, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
    : socket_(io_service, context)
  {
    socket_.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_peer);
    socket_.set_verify_callback(boost::bind(&client::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));

    boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator, boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  bool verify_certificate(bool preverified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
  {
    char subject_name[256];
    X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
    std::cout << "Verifying:\n" << subject_name << std::endl;

    return preverified;
  }

  void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if(!error){
      std::cout << "Connection OK!" << std::endl;
      socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client, boost::bind(&client::handle_handshake, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }else{
      std::cout << "Connect failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  }

  void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if(!error){
      std::cout << "Sending request: " << std::endl;

      std::stringstream request_;

      request_ << "GET HTTP/1.1\r\n";
      request_ << "Host: google.com\r\n";
      request_ << "Accept-Encoding: *\r\n";
      request_ << "\r\n";

      std::cout << request_.str() << std::endl;

      boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(request_.str()), boost::bind(&client::handle_write, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }else{
      std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error){
      std::cout << "Sending request OK!" << std::endl;
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(reply_, bytes_transferred), boost::bind(&client::handle_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }else{
      std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  }

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error){
      std::cout << "Reply: ";
      std::cout.write(reply_, bytes_transferred);
      std::cout << "\n";
    }else{
      std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;
  char reply_[0x1 << 16];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("www.google.com", "443");
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    boost::asio::ssl::context context(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
    context.add_verify_path("/home/mint/workspace/BoostExamples/certs");
    client c(io_service, context, iterator);
    io_service.run();
  }catch (std::exception& e){
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

With the following error:

```
Connection OK!
Verifying:
/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
Handshake failed: certificate verify failed
```

I think I'm loading the certificates correctly, but am not sure and it's not clear to me how to get more information out of Boost to shed more light on the problem. I'm on Linux Mint so I don't know whether the Debian issues with SSL 3 are also coming into play. Extensive searching and reading the Boost.Asio documentation haven't helped, either. There's lots of reference material but not much explanation.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong, or how to find out what's causing the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include relevant code (preferably a [sscce](http://sscce.org)) in the question itself and not as a link to another website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code you have posted I can, at the moment, only see one more or less obvious reason.

It seems like you simply return the `preverified` bool in the `verify_certificate(...)` function straight off. What if this is `false`? Which it would be if boost has not preverified it. Your function should do the verification - you don't...

Try returning true. If it works, look below.

I can grant you that the code you have should work out of the box, since it's the boost example code. But it could be that your `context.add_verify_path("/home/mint/workspace/BoostExamples/certs");` messes it up...
Or rather, that the file in the directory does not have the expected name. From the reference:

```
Each file in the directory must contain a single certificate.
The files must be named using the subject name's hash and an extension of ".0".
```

Comment: Yes, the issue was with the `preverified` bool (my certificates are in the correct format). When I return `true`, it works - thanks!

However, this means that the example will not work when copied-and-pasted from the Boost site. Perhaps I should let them know too so they can update it?

Comment: The example probably will work - It does not add another path for certificates. Did you verify the name of your certificate files?

Comment: I should also mention that just returning true will mean that *all* certificates are accepted!

Comment: Connection OK!
Verifying:
/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
Verifying:
/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
Verifying:
/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com
Sending request:
GET HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
Accept-Encoding: *


Sending request OK!
Reply: HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; chars

and it stops

Answer (score 12):

#### `OpenSSL` might do the work for you:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ...
    boost::asio::ssl::context context(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
    context.set_default_verify_paths();
    ...
}
```

Boost uses OpenSSL `SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths()` under the hood.

**From boost docs:**

> Configures the context to use the default directories for finding certification authority certificates.

See also
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/set_default_verify_paths.html